# sort .mat format file based on two fields in MATLAB

Tags: sorting, matlab

Please, I have mat format file include structure of array , the structure include many field like ClassNam and DispNo..etc. I would like to sort this file depending on ClassNam then DispNo.. I did sort the file depending on ClassNam using:

```
[ClaNa,index] = sort([ SimiMeaGabor50.ClassNam],'ascend');
```

How can I sort this file depending on two fieldw?
... any one can help me please.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort a structure array `S` based first on the value in field `'field1'` and then on the value in field `'field2'`, you can use the function [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) as follows:

```
[sortedData,sortIndex] = sortrows([S.field1; S.field2].',[1 2]);  %'
S = S(sortIndex);
```